# How can I center H1 with border, while dropping display:inline?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, css

Ok, this is an interesting one.

I have a `<h1>` header that appears in a box (I mean an on-screen visible box, like `border:solid 3px white`). The box itself as well as the text inside needs to have a shadow. The box can't be a fixed width, as the text inside the box changes from page to page.

Here's the issue: I have it working perfectly except in IE9, where the shadow only appears on the box, not the text.

If I remove `display:inline` from the CSS, then it works right in IE9, but then the box is the width of the entire container, instead of wrapping just around the text. So I think the key to the solution is just finding a better way to center the text and the box inside of the container, so `display:inline;` can be dropped.

The markup is very simple:

```
<style>
.container {
    width:500px;height:200px;padding:50px;background:#eee;
    text-align:center;
}

h1 {
    font-size:34px;
    color:white;
    padding:25px;
    border:solid 3px white;
    letter-spacing:7px;
    display:inline;

    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #666;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    filter:glow(color=black, strength=1); /* IE9 stupid proprietary shadow */
}
</style>

<div class='container'>
    <h1>Testing</h1>
</div>
```

And you can play with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/j434X/4/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I added a `margin` property in the h1. This makes it possible to get rid of `display: inline;` and still get the same result, but longer text skips to another line. Kind of like if you had a set width, which I know you didn't want. [Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j434X/6/) anyway, if it helps

Comment: Thanks-- but unfortunately, per the designer, the text has to look just like the original example, with the box 25px away from the text (thus the 25px padding on the h1). This looks good and works but I can't have that set width. Do you know a trick to center everything without using the set width?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. I tried setting `width: inherit;` and even making a new div to contain the h1 and passing the box shadow and border to it, but still didn't work. This is a tough one, i voted the question up so hopefully you can get someone with some more experience than me. IE is a shit shoot sometimes. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for trying :-) I agree, I can't believe we're all the way up to IE9 and it's *still* a gigantic pain in the ass!